# solutions for the diophantine equation $x^2+y^2=n$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Are there any solutions for the diophantine equation $x^2+y^2=n$ ?

For $n \in \mathbb{P} \wedge n \equiv1\pmod4$  solutions are widely known.

Can we generalize a bit?

Comment: A lot. A positive integer $n$ is representable if and only if it has prime factorization of the form $2^e p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_k^{a_k}q_1^{2b_1}\cdots q_l^{2b_l}$, where the $p_i$ are primes congrient to $1$ modulo $4$,and the $q_i$ are primes congruent to $3$ modulo $4$.  (It is possible to have $k=0$ and/or $l=0$.)

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta-Fibonacci_identity.

Comment: Thank you! So we get answers only by a (partial) factorization of $n$ ?

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/29644/enumerating-ways-to-decompose-an-integer-into-the-sum-of-two-squares.

Comment: Thank you! That is new for me. But I'm afraid we can't get rid of a factorization of $n$ at this point.